# Activiti Editor not working when i run Activiti-webapp-explorer 5.18.0 under tomcat

Tags: java, activiti

when I deploy activiti-webapp-explorer2 (5.18.0) under tomcat, project run perfect. But when I create new module in workflow designer workspace the activiti editor not working just blank page.[Activiti Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t42VV.png)

Chrome Developer Tools show javascript error:[Error Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2seq4.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Likely this is a javascript error.
Check your browser console and see what errors are reports.
Greg